# State doesn't changes with the props

Tags: javascript, reactjs

[image: Grid info]I have a component renderer that is something like

```
const renderToggle = ({rowData}) => {
  const {isPresent, id} = rowData
  const [checkedVal, setCheckedVal] = useState(isPresent)
  const handleChange = () => setCheckedVal(!checkedVal)
  return (
    <input type='checkbox' value={checkedVal} onChange={handleChangle} />
  )
}
```

And I am rendering this on a component's useEffect

```
const RoomAttendance = ({roomAttendanceConfig}) => {
  const [tempData, setTempData] = useState({headerConfig: []})
  useEffect(() => {
    const updatedMetaDataConfig = roomAttendanceConfig.map((item) => {
      if(item.label === 'Is Present'){
        return {...item, customComponent: ({rowData}) => renderToggle({rowData})
      }
    })
    setTempMetaData({headerConfig: [...item, ]})
  })
  return(
    <Grid metaData={tempData} />
  )
}
```

The issue is, in renderToggle component isPresent is passed to checkedVal and when the grid changes and load different form data it still shows the same checkedVal to the toggler.
That is something like - isPresent = true where as checkedVal = false
So that checked Val shows incorrect value to my toggle button.
I will appreciate any suggestions on this.

Real room attendance code is

```
import React, { useEffect, useLayoutEffect, useState } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import Button from 'pepcus-core/lib/Button';
import DataGrid from '@pepcus/react-simple-data-grid';
import Toggle from '../../common/Toggle';
import { isMarkAttendanceFailed, isMarkAttendanceSuccess } from 'reducers/allMembersDataReducer';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import Alerts from '../../common/Alert';
import { getConstants } from 'reducers/constants';
import styled from 'styled-components';

const RoomAttendanceGrid = ({
    attendanceResults,
    roomAttendanceGridConfig,
    onSubmit,
    isApiSuccess,
    isApiFailure,
    constants,
    refreshAttendance,
}) => {
    const [tempPresentIds, setTempPresentIds] = useState([]);
    const [tempAbsentIds, setTempAbsentIds] = useState([]);
    const [tempMetaData, setTempMetaData] = useState({ headerConfig: [] });

    useLayoutEffect(() => {
        if (attendanceResults !== null) {
            if (attendanceResults.absentCount !== '0' || attendanceResults.presentCount !== '0') {
                let presentIds = [];
                let absentIds = [];
                const { attendance } = attendanceResults;
                const { headerConfig } = roomAttendanceGridConfig;
                const updatedMetaDataConfig = headerConfig.map((item) => {
                    if (item.label === 'Is Present') {
                        return {
                            ...item,
                            customComponent: ({ rowData }) => {
                                const { isPresent, id } = rowData;
                                const [checkedVal, setCheckedVal] = useState(isPresent);
                                console.log(
                                    `row data present id and checked value`,
                                    isPresent,
                                    id,
                                    checkedVal
                                );
                                // Value of isPresent and value of CheckedVal differs on changing form data and it renders the grid but with previous value of isPresent that is injected to checkedVal state but no longer is same for the new form data's grid.

                                const onHandleChange = () => {
                                    setCheckedVal((s) => !s);
                                };

                                return (
                                    <Toggle
                                        checked={checkedVal}
                                        id={id}
                                        onChange={(isPresent) => {
                                            onHandleChange();
                                            if (isPresent) {
                                                !presentIds.includes(id) &&
                                                    isPresent &&
                                                    presentIds.push(id);
                                                absentIds.includes(id) &&
                                                    isPresent &&
                                                    absentIds.splice(
                                                        absentIds.findIndex(
                                                            (indexId) => indexId === id
                                                        ),
                                                        1
                                                    );
                                            } else {
                                                !absentIds.includes(id) &&
                                                    !isPresent &&
                                                    absentIds.push(id);
                                                presentIds.includes(id) &&
                                                    !isPresent &&
                                                    presentIds.splice(
                                                        presentIds.findIndex(
                                                            (indexId) => indexId === id
                                                        ),
                                                        1
                                                    );
                                            }
                                        }}
                                    />
                                );
                            },
                        };
                    } else {
                        return { ...item };
                    }
                });

                if (!tempPresentIds.length || !tempAbsentIds.length) {
                    if (tempMetaData.headerConfig.length === 0) {
                        setTempMetaData({ headerConfig: updatedMetaDataConfig });
                    }
                    // setTempMetaData({ headerConfig: updatedMetaDataConfig });
                    attendance.forEach((item) => {
                        item.isPresent && presentIds.push(item.id);
                        !item.isPresent && absentIds.push(item.id);
                    });
                    setTempPresentIds(presentIds);
                    setTempAbsentIds(absentIds);
                }
            } else {
                return undefined;
            }
        }
    }, [attendanceResults]);
    if (attendanceResults) {
        const { attendance = [], absentCount, presentCount } = attendanceResults;
        const totalCount = parseInt(absentCount) + parseInt(presentCount);
        const { MARK_ATTENDANCE_SUCCESS_MESSAGE, MARK_ATTENDANCE_FAILED_MESSAGE } = constants;

        return (
            <div>
                {isApiSuccess && (
                    <Alerts
                        message={MARK_ATTENDANCE_SUCCESS_MESSAGE}
                        type={'success'}
                        handleAfterAlert={refreshAttendance}
                        autoHide={true}
                    />
                )}
                {isApiFailure && (
                    <Alerts
                        message={MARK_ATTENDANCE_FAILED_MESSAGE}
                        type={'danger'}
                        autoHide={false}
                    />
                )}
                <DataGrid
                    data={attendance}
                    metaData={tempMetaData}
                    styles={{
                        gridWrapper: {
                            width: '100%',
                        },
                    }}
                />
                <StyledGridAttendanceBottomSection>
                    <StyledGridAttendanceCount>
                        <div>{`${presentCount} Present | ${absentCount} Absent`}</div>
                        <StyledGridRecordCount>{`Total records: ${totalCount}`}</StyledGridRecordCount>
                    </StyledGridAttendanceCount>
                    <StyledGridAttendanceButtonContainer>
                        <Button
                            margin="0 0 20px 0px"
                            noMinWidth
                            onClick={() => {
                                onSubmit({ tempPresentIds, tempAbsentIds });
                            }}>
                            {`SUBMIT`}
                        </Button>
                    </StyledGridAttendanceButtonContainer>
                </StyledGridAttendanceBottomSection>
            </div>
        );
    }
    return null;
};

RoomAttendanceGrid.propTypes = {
    constants: PropTypes.object,
    attendanceResults: PropTypes.object,
    roomAttendanceGridConfig: PropTypes.object,
    onSubmit: PropTypes.func,
    isApiSuccess: PropTypes.bool,
    isApiFailure: PropTypes.bool,
    isAttendanceMarkSuccess: PropTypes.bool,
    isAttendanceMarkFailed: PropTypes.bool,
    refreshAttendance: PropTypes.func,
};

const StyledGridAttendanceBottomSection = styled.div`
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-content: center;
`;

const StyledGridAttendanceCount = styled.div`
    display: flex;
    text-align: center;
    flex-direction: column;
    font-weight: 600;
    font-size: 15px;
    line-height: 21px;
    letter-spacing: 0.02em;
    color: #4c4c4c;
`;

const StyledGridRecordCount = styled.div`
    font-weight: 500;
    font-size: 16px;
    letter-spacing: 0;
    margin-top: 10px;
`;

const StyledGridAttendanceButtonContainer = styled.div`
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 20px;

    button {
        padding: 8px 45px;
    }
`;

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
    isAttendanceMarkFailed: isMarkAttendanceFailed(state),
    isAttendanceMarkSuccess: isMarkAttendanceSuccess(state),
    constants: getConstants(state),
});
export default connect(mapStateToProps)(RoomAttendanceGrid);
```

Comment: You need to start from scratch, almost all of this is wrong as far as following how react should be written. dont make functions that return components jsx like renderToggle, make it a component and map it in the grid as a child. also your useEffect does not have any  dependencies and will fire on every render which you probably don't want.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on what you're trying to do rather than saying what the values will be in the code. It makes easier for people to understand and faster answers for you.
 Can you rephrase the question and explain a bit more on what you're trying to achieve.Thanks

Comment: I have a form that fetches the attendance. Form takes day and selected room no. And the grid displays grid data belonging to that day or room no. When the first time grid renders it shows correct toggled values. But if you change the day and the grid renders it shows the first instance of toggled values. @SharanBalakrishnan let me know if I am confusing you. I will post a screenshot of the form and grid then.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Errors in this piece of code]

There are two major issues even within this small piece of code.

1. When you created the useState you've named the set function as **setTempData** when calling it the name is  **setTempMetaData**
2. The useEffect does not have a **dependency array**, it is a syntax error and i don't know how you can miss that.

If none of this makes any sense, first please get the basics of react right.
Hope this helps and Sorry If I understood incorrectly

Comment: I am sorry but that was a typing error, it is setTempData only. I have tried using the dependency array but that doesn't work either.

Comment: Dependency array is a must, it doesn't matter if code works or not. Can you post the entire Roomattendance component in the question please!

Comment: Sure.. but that's a bit too lengthy. Let me edit and post that